# Use vue3 component in js file

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

I have a vue3 project, using axios and a custom component "statusMessage" that I wrote. My configuration of axios is a little bit much, so I created a http.js file, where I create the axios instance like this:

```
import axios from 'axios';
import { cacheAdapterEnhancer } from 'axios-extensions';

const instance = axios.create({
    headers: { 'content-type': 'application/json' },
    adapter: cacheAdapterEnhancer(axios.defaults.adapter, { enabledByDefault: false, cacheFlag: 'useCache' }), // Funktioniert aktuell wegen axios Bug nicht https://github.com/axios/axios/pull/2207
});

// ... more stuff happening here ... 

export default instance;
```

Now in my main.js, I use it like this:

```
import { http } from '.services/http';
import StatusMessageComponent from './components/statusMessage/StatusMessageComponent';

const app = createApp(App, {});
app.use(StatusMessageComponent);
app.config.globalProperties.$axios = http;
app.mount('#app');
```

and my statusMessageComponent looks like this:

```
export default {
    install(app, options) {

        let methods = {
            message(message, type) {
                // code...
            },
            clear() {
                // more code ... 
            },
        };

        app.$statusMessage = methods;
        app.config.globalProperties.$statusMessage = methods;
    },
};
```

so far, so good, this works as intended. In my components, I can access this.$axios and this.$statusMessage

Now, I need to add an interceptor to my http.js file and if something there goes wrong, I would like to use my statusMessage component to output some info. The question is: how do I access my component or the app instance in general?

```
instance.interceptors.response.use(
    (response) => {
        
    },
    (error) => {
        // I would need app.$statusMessage here
        statusMessage.message();
        return Promise.reject(error);
    }
);
```

I tried to to add.provide in my main.js and inject in my http.js, but that results in

```
[Vue warn]: inject() can only be used inside setup() or functional components.
```

Any hints on how I achieve this?

Comment: statusMessageComponent is not a component, it's a plugin. You omitted the implementation that can be relevant. Either make it a regular ES module that can be imported anywhere including interceptor module. There are not so many reasons for code to be a plugin. Or do vice versa and define axios interceptor inside a plugin or main.js where you have access to `app` or whatever you need to make a plugin work